# Boot failure after using 4k Grub theme on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, acpi, secure-boot

I have downloaded and installed the wrong version of this grub theme.
here is the ref if you wish to inspect their code https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1307852/
It should be (1080p) not 4k. As the result my linux crashed after I click to boot any linux version.

[Here is the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLPsE.jpg)

### [Here is the grub screen in case you might want to inspect it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHlqY.jpg)

Here are what I have done so far:

1. add acpi=off, acpi=strict, or acpi=force in grub does not work 
   [acpi=off screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQYWy.jpg)
2. try add noapic and acpi=off leads to blank screen
3. I have try both method on other boot option(kernel 4.15.0.66-generic)
   leads to same result as above
4. adding 3 hoping to get into terminal does not work
5. I try using boot Live/USB but still does not work 
   [Using boot live screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BwRC.jpg) apply both noapic and acpi=off return me this

```
Couldn't get size: 0x80000000000000010
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
Couldn't get size: 0x80000000000000010
```

6. Seeing error on No.5, I have tried to turn off secure boot on BIOS hoping to get into Boot live/USB but it does not work 
   [Secure Boot on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4REj.jpg)[Secure boot off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DML8q.jpg)
7. I tried APM Configuration but failed. I disable and enable ErP(s4=s5)ready (might not related but hope that might trigger something about ACPI)
8. I saw some trouble shooting https://bugzilla.redhat.com/attachment.cgi?id=1334270&action=diff for "MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list" Do we have to go this far becuase I install the wrong Grub Theme version ?
9. I have tried boot it manually choosing drive from grub (hd2,gpt2) and (hd1,1) but it does not work

any suggestions ?

Many thanks

Comment: PC: 
i5 8400 cpu@2.80 
Motherboard: TUF B360M -Plus Gaming Bios ver.0224  
VGA: gtx 1070 nvidia driver 435 (proprietary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
you just need to turn on "Intel Rapid storage technology" on your BIOS.
```

If Above still cause some error you might also want to set

```
DRAM Frequency , DRAM Voltage, DRAM CAS# Latency, DRAM RAS# to CAS# Delay, and DRAM RAS# ACT Time -> all set to auto
```